# Javascript array assinging to variable gets undefined

Tags: javascript

Hello what i am trying to do is just to draw few images .so at first i made a group(i think this function is a part of a plugin i am using but thats no matter) then i made an array to store a name and src of several images and then i am calling a for loop to draw those images but the thing is i got no results at all no errors nothing so i try to alert "b.name" and "b.src" but result i got is undefined could someone explain me where is a problem cuz for me its seems everything good

```
            var mapGroup = new Group();
            var mapVillage = [
                {name: "leaf", src: "js/leaf.png"},
                {name: "sand", src: "js/sand.png"},
                {name: "stone", src: "js/stone.png"},
                {name: "cloud", src: "js/cloud.png"},
                {name: "mist", src: "js/mist.png"},
                {name: "rain", src: "js/rain.png"},
                {name: "grass", src: "js/grass.png"},
                {name: "sound", src: "js/sound.png"},
                {name: "hotwater", src: "js/hotwater.png"},
                {name: "waterfall", src: "js/waterfall.png"}
            ];

            for(var i = 0; i < mapVillage.length; i++){
                var b = mapVillage[i];
                b = new Sprite(game.width, game.height);
                b.image = game.assets[b.src];
                alert(b.name);
                mapGroup.addChild(b);
            }
```

Comment: You're overriding `b` in `var b = mapVillage[i]; b = new Sprite(game.width, game.height);`

Comment: The variable `b` cannot be both an entry in the `mapVillage` array and a new Sprite at the same time.

Comment: i think i was trying to assing a sprite for each array element cuz later i am going to do hittest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your mistake is here

```
   var b = mapVillage[i];
   b = new Sprite(game.width, game.height);
```

You are assigning b first to an entry of mapVillage, which does have the `b.image` you are looking for. But you are overriding it in the next line. So when you are calling `b.image` next, it is looking for 'image' on a "Sprite", which does not have that property ;-)

To solve it, simply assign the Sprite to a new variable. 
`var sprite = new Sprite(game.width, game.height);`

Answer (score 1):

You first assign to var `b` an object (`var b = mapVillage[i];`) then override it assigning a `Sprite` to it. You need two variables, something like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < mapVillage.length; i++){
  var b = mapVillage[i];
  var sprite = new Sprite(game.width, game.height);
  sprite.image = game.assets[b.src];
  alert(b.name);
  mapGroup.addChild(sprite);
}
```